# Hiding Internal State of CoffeeScript Object

Tags: coffeescript, information-hiding

Looking at the following from [CoffeeScript Ristretto](https://leanpub.com/coffeescript-ristretto/read#fargs):

```
QueueMaker = ->
  do (queue = undefined) ->
    array: []
    head: 0
    tail: -1
    pushTail: (value) ->
      queue.array[tail += 1] = value
    pullHead: ->
      unless queue.isEmpty()
        do (value = queue.array[queue.head]) ->
          queue.array[queue.head] = undefined
          queue.head += 1
          value
      isEmpty: ->
        queue.tail < queue.head
```

It's possible to mutate `queue.head` - http://jsfiddle.net/VQLNG/.

```
queue = QueueMaker()
queue.head = 666
console.log queue
```

How can I write the above function so that `head` isn't public?

Comment: You left off a `    queue = ` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have private properties so CoffeeScript doesn't have them either.

However, you can simulate private properties in many cases by using function scopes to hide things and closures to access the *hidden* things.

A simple stack implementation should demonstrate the technique:

```
Stack = ->
    stack = [ ]
    push: (e) -> stack.push(e)
    pop:      -> stack.pop()
    toArray:  -> stack.slice()
```

`stack` is a local variable in the `Stack` function so it cannot be accessed or seen from outside `Stack`. The `push` and `pop` functions simply proxy to the `stack` array and the `toArray` function is the only way to see what `stack` looks like. Only those three functions have access to `stack` so it is effectively private and each time you call `Stack`, you get a new local `stack`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/C8V5R/

Adapting your queue to use this technique to hide `array`, `head` and `tail` is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks, mu, for your continued help. Is it better/worse/same to define  `stack` inside `do (stack = []) ->` after `Stack = ->` - http://jsfiddle.net/C8V5R/1/? I'm curious from an idiomatic CoffeeScript point of view.

Comment: All `do` does is add a self-invoking function wrapper (see the bottom of the [**Loops and Comprehensions**](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) section of the fine manual), I don't see any reason for it here, looks like pointless indirection and complication to me.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `QueueMaker` is a JavaScript object, with `head` being one of it's fields. Object fields are mutable, with no option for protected status.

Even with `QueueMaker` rewritten as a CoffeeScript class, and head being an instance variable, it would still be mutable from outside the object scope.

CoffeeScript can only support the language level features of JavaScript, which does not support private/protected keywords. Sadly.

Answer (score 0):

```
QueueMaker = ->
  do (array = [], head = 0, tail = -1) ->
    pushTail: (value) ->
      array[tail += 1] = value
    pullHead: ->
      if tail >= head
        do (value = array[head]) ->
          array[head] = undefined
          head += 1
          value
    isEmpty: ->
      tail < head
```

With this version, `array`, `head` and `tail` are hidden.  They are initialed when the `queue` is created, and remain in existence only as long as it exists.

```
coffee> queue = QueueMaker()
{ pushTail: [Function],
  pullHead: [Function],
  isEmpty: [Function] }

coffee> queue.head
undefined
```

But to be honest, this is the first version of `QueueMaker` on the Ristretto link.  What you gave us was the `“de-encapsulate”` version, rewritten purposely to make these variables visible (in order to extend its behavior).

For reference, the "de-encapuslated" version is:

```
QueueMaker = ->
  do (queue = undefined) ->
    queue = 
      array: []
      head: 0
      tail: -1
      pushTail: ...
      pullHead: ...
```

Your question omitted the `queue=` line.  Now the purpose of the `do()->` should be clearer.